# Using Microsoft.Office in MS VS Express 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ms-office

I'm currently trying to use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.(...) in MS VS Express 2012 for C#, but I can't seem to find any way to install it.

Does MS VS 2010 Tools for Office Runtime have anything to do with this?

Any help to get me started will be appreciated!

EDIT: I might add that I don't have MS Office (any version) installed on my computer. I don't know if there are some packages there I should have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the Redistr

[Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508)

Comment: I did, but I'm not sure if it worked. The download extracted a .msi which I executed, but there were no confirmation of any kind after the installation.
There are also no new options in the "Refereces"-tab in VS.

Comment: Forget it, the problem resolved itself!
For some reason the Office Tools didn't show up in the reference tables, but when I specifically searched for it after the installation, it was there.